# Pulse shaping time related to number of counts?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, electronics, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

I have a PMT (with a proton recoil neutron detector) hooked up to an amplifier, and when I increase the pulse shaping time from 0.5 microseconds to 2 microseconds, the number of counts recorded by the MCA (on MAESTRO software spectra) reduces. How are they correlated, and why does increasing the shaping time decrease the number of counts? My source is a Californium source.

Comment: It's a good question! Why not take a moment and record the rate at each shaping time you have, and list or plot the data. Then move the source closer, and also farther to change the rate, and do it again. Then plot your data again, but think about the rate as *counts per shaping time*. When that ratio exceeds  say 10% and approaches unity, can you imagine what might be the consequences?

Comment: @uhoh I could try that, but I've already noticed the change, I'm just wondering how the two are related?